# Can you call the attention of a user through an answer?

Tags: support, answers, notifications

Is it possible to call the attention of a user through the use of an answer post. For example, in comments, if one wants to notify a user they can use:

```
@user blah blah blah
```

Would this work in the same way if I included in my answer, for example, something like:

```
@user answer works, but this is better 
...CODE BLOCK...
```

Comment: No, the user does not get notified if this is done within an answer. The original poster is notified when there is a new answer to his question, and fellow commentators are notified and when posting comments using the `@user` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to call attention to any user this way.. except the question asker will obviously receive a notification that you left an answer.. whether or not you did @questionAsker. And it's not good to do @questionAsker anyways in an answer.

If you want to notify a different user that already posted an answer on that page, you will have to settle for using comments on their answer. If you want to notify a different comment user then you can do the @user to notify them.